# Missing "Minimum Access - Salesforce" Profile in Patch Orgs

Tags: profile, winter22, spring21

For some specific reason, in a `Winter '22` patch org, "Minimum Access - Salesforce" profile doesn't exist, which should replace "Read Only" profile after [the change introduced](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_profiles_and_perms_read_only_new.htm&type=5&release=230) in `Spring ’21`.

Any idea what could be the reason? Are the patch orgs profile limited?

This issue is causing our fflib tests to fail, and it would be great to find a non-workaround solution.

[image: Profiles available in a current Patch Org]

Answer (score 3):

The profile Minimum Access - Salesforce is created when the tenant edition license PartnerDeveloperEdition is provisioned, but the patch orgs don't have it.This has been reported as a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001TuS2QAK) and an internal bug has already been logged for the same.

Can you log a case with salesforce support team so they can help you on it.

Comment: Makes sense, although I would like to see docs that state how the "Minimum Access - Salesforce" profile is provided by the "PartnerDeveloperEdition" license. According to the current doc, that profile should be given in all orgs (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.standard_profiles.htm&type=5)
Logged also a SF case for this.